# Underestanding how variables are stored in memory

Tags: python

I'm trying to underestand deeply how python works.

I've been testing how the variables are store in the memory using python and I had found that if you declare two variables with the same value, both have the same memory id.

```
a = 4
b = 4

print(id(a), id(b))
```

Why is that?

Comment: In Python, you don't declare variables. Variables are just names that refer to objects. The integer literal expression you used to create those object happens to use cached objects (indeed, all small integers are cached in Python), but that is an optimization of the runtime, which is possible because `int` objects are immutable

Comment: This is an *implementation detail* that shouldn't be relied on